# ejabberd - Get publisher JID in pubsub item

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html#impl-association defines an attribute called 'itemreply' that lets you add the publisher information along with the item being published. It doesn't look like ejabberd has implemented the above option. Is there any other workaround for this ?

According to https://support.process-one.net/browse/EJAB-1347 there is an patch available that can accomplish it but i am not sure on how to apply the patch. Looking for guidance on the same.

Thanks,
Mithun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to change the code to add publisher information. Here are the steps needed to to the same.

1) open the file src/mod_pubsub.erl

2) Find the following function

```
itemAttr(ItemId) -> [{<<"id">>, ItemId}].
```

3) Add a new function below the above mentioned function

```
itemAttr(ItemId, From) -> [{<<"id">>, ItemId},{<<"publisher">>, From}].
```

4) Next find the function named

```
broadcast_publish_item(Host, Node, Nidx, Type, NodeOptions, ItemId, From, Payload, Removed) ->
```

5) Replace

```
Stanza = event_stanza(
                [#xmlel{name = <<"items">>, attrs = nodeAttr(Node),
                        children = [#xmlel{name = <<"item">>, attrs = itemAttr(ItemId),
                                children = Content}]}]),
```

with

```
Stanza = event_stanza(
                [#xmlel{name = <<"items">>, attrs = nodeAttr(Node),
                        children = [#xmlel{name = <<"item">>, attrs = itemAttr(ItemId, jlib:jid_to_string(From)),
                                children = Content}]}]),
```

6) Recompile the code using

```
sudo make; sudo make install;
```

Restart your server and you should get the publisher information along with the item being published.

Answer (score 0):

The patch is too old to apply as is on ejabberd code base. It would need to be updated to latest version, but I do not think it is a highly requested feature.

You should probably submit a feature request on project Github: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues

Comment: I have a requirement where i need to implement MUC using pubsub and hence needed the above feature. I will submit a feature request. Hoping it gets implemented in the next release.